# Splitting DataFrames based on timestamp continuity in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, split

I want to create a new DataFrame consisting of the rows corresponding to the value 1.0 or NaN in the last column, whereby I only take the Nans under a 1.0. However, I also want to consider the rows where the Result 0.0 as long as there are maximum two such timestamps (for instance, in the simple example below, I would take the rows where the Timestamp is 00-00-30 and 00-00-40).

```
Timestamp  Value         Result    
00-00-10   34567          1.0  
00-00-20   45425     
00-00-30   46773          0.0  
00-00-40   64567   
00-00-50   25665          1.0  
00-01-00   25678  
00-01-10   84358 
00-01-20   76869          0.0
00-01-30   95830          
00-01-40   87890        
00-01-50   99537            
00-02-00   85957          1.0
00-02-10   58840
```

I split it into two dataframes:

```
df_1 = data[((data['Result'].isnull()) & data['Result'].ffill() == 1) | data.Result == 1]
```

and

```
df_2 = data[((data['Result'].isnull()) & data['Result'].ffill() == 0) | data.Result == 0]
```

How do I split `df_2` into blocks such that the Timestamp is continuous/not interrupted? (Then I can check whether each block is greater than the tolerated length, and if not, append it to `df_1`and sort it based on time.)

I therefore want the output:

```
Timestamp  Value         Result    
00-00-10   34567          1.0  
00-00-20   45425     
00-00-30   46773          0.0  
00-00-40   64567   
00-00-50   25665          1.0  
00-01-00   25678  
00-01-10   84358 
00-02-00   85957          1.0
00-02-10   58840
```

Comment: Given the dataframe you have, what should be the desired output you are looking for? Please add it to your question.

Comment: @AllaTarighati Thank you, I edited the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make a `mask` that satisfies all three conditions, and then subset the original `DataFrame`

```
mask = (
        (df.Result == 1) 
        | (df.Result.ffill() == 1)
        | ((df.Result.ffill() == 0) 
           & (df.groupby((df.Result.ffill() != df.Result.ffill().shift()).cumsum()).Result.transform('size') <= 2))
       )
```

Output: `df[mask]`

```
   Timestamp  Value  Result
0   00-00-10  34567     1.0
1   00-00-20  45425     NaN
2   00-00-30  46773     0.0
3   00-00-40  64567     NaN
4   00-00-50  25665     1.0
5   00-01-00  25678     NaN
6   00-01-10  84358     NaN
11  00-02-00  85957     1.0
12  00-02-10  58840     NaN
```

Explanation:
You have three conditions

1. Keep if Result == 1
2. Keep if it's a Nan below Result == 1 (accomplished with `.ffill()`)
3. The third condition determines the size of consecutive groups, and we keep if it's a consecutive group of `0` with a size `<= 2`

Answer (score 1):

Example data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Timestamp': ['00-00-10', '00-00-20', '00-00-30', '00-00-40', 
                   '00-00-50', '00-01-00', '00-01-10', '00-01-20', 
                   '00-01-30', '00-01-40', '00-01-50', '00-02-00', 
                   '00-02-10'],
      'Value': range(0, 13),
      'Result': [1.0, None, 0.0, None, 1.0, None, None, 0.0, None, None, None, 1.0, None]})
```

Code:

```
#where NaN after 1
df1 = df.shift(-1)[df.Result == 1] 
#where 1
df2 = df[df.Result==1]
#index where 0 with max Timestamp
ind = df[df.Timestamp == min(df[df.Result == 0].Timestamp)[df.Result==0].index[0]
#select by ind and one next
df3 = df.loc[[ind, ind+1]]
```

Output:

```
    Result Timestamp  Value
0      NaN  00-00-20    1.0
4      NaN  00-01-00    5.0
11     NaN  00-02-10   12.0
0      1.0  00-00-10    0.0
4      1.0  00-00-50    4.0
11     1.0  00-02-00   11.0
2      0.0  00-00-30    2.0
3      NaN  00-00-40    3.0
```

Then you can sorted by index, if you want.
I hope it helps. But I'm not sure that I understand you about last select.
And I don't understand why you have a raw with "00-01-10" in result.